# vector of call back functions and function pointer binding

Tags: c++

I am new to the `std::function` and trying to implement a callback function. In the following code "Callback_t" contains a function that holds a vector of function to be called. Class "other" is  a nested class inside "SomeClass". An object of "SomeClass" contains an array of nested class object "b". The "other" class constructor assigns a function pointer to "fptr". I push this function in to the vector of callback class "Callback_t". When I run this code, I get the segmentation fault when the first function in the vector is invoked.  I am not able to figure out what is wrong with the statement

```
this->loc_ptr->set_of_cb.push_back(this->b[i].fptr);
```

However if I replace it with

```
this->loc_ptr->set_of_cb.push_back(std::bind(&other::func, &(this->b[i])))
```

the code works perfectly. I need help to understand what's wrong with the original statement.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
typedef std::function<void(void)> func_type;
class Callback_t {
public:
    std::vector<func_type> set_of_cb;
    void myCallback()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < set_of_cb.size(); i ++){
                set_of_cb[i]();
        }
    }
};
class SomeClass;
class SomeClass {
private:
        Callback_t *loc_ptr;
        int a[10];
        class other{
                public:
                int id;
                SomeClass *loc;
                func_type fptr;
                other(){};
                other(SomeClass *loc, int id){
                        this->id = id;
                        this->loc =loc;
                        fptr = std::bind(&other::func,this);
                }
                void func(void){
                        this->loc->a[id] = loc->a[id] * id;
                        return;
                }
        };

public:
    other *b;

    //other b[10];
    SomeClass(Callback_t *a = nullptr){
        this->loc_ptr = a;
         this->b = new other[10];
        for(int i =0; i <10;i++){
                this->a[i] = i;
                this->b[i] = other(this, i);
                this->loc_ptr->set_of_cb.push_back(this->b[i].fptr);
        }
    }
    void read(void){
        for(int i =0; i <10;i++){
                std::cout<<a[i]<<std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Callback_t *tmp;
    tmp = new Callback_t;
    SomeClass tmp1(tmp);
    tmp1.read();
    tmp->myCallback();
    tmp1.read();
    delete tmp;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            other(SomeClass *loc, int id){
                    this->id = id;
                    this->loc =loc;
                    fptr = std::bind(&other::func,this);
            }
```

The constructor binds `fptr` to `this`, which is the constructed object. Now, pay careful attention:

```
  this->b[i] = other(this, i);
```

This performs the following sequence of events. There are quite a few things happening here, that are crucial to this mystery:

1. A temporary `other` object gets constructed, and its constructor does what it does. Note that the object is temporary, so its constructor ends up binding its `fptr` to a temporary object! You're beginning to see the problem, but let's close the loop, anyway:
2. The object gets assigned to `this->b[i]`. This is effectively a copy.
3. The original temporary objects gets destroyed.

The end result is that `b[i]`'s bound function ends up getting bound to a temporary object that is now destroyed. This results in undefined behavior and your crash.

And with your working alternative:

```
this->loc_ptr->set_of_cb.push_back(std::bind(&other::func, &(this->b[i])))
```

You are binding the `std::function` to a valid instance of the object, in `b[i]`.

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer explains what is going wrong in your code. What is left to do is to show case a more canonical example of achieving what you go for (with a little help from lambda functions).  Of course, `std::bind()` also works, but it is pre C++11 and I think nowadays most would rather do it as I do in my code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

class Foo {
public:
    void FooFun() {
        std::cout << "Foo::FooFun() called" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Bar {
public:
    void BarFun() {
        std::cout << "Bar::BarFun() called" << std::endl;
    }
};

using CallbackFun_t = std::function<void()>; 
using Callbacks_t = std::vector<CallbackFun_t>;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Foo foo{};
    Bar bar{};

    Callbacks_t callbacks
        { [&foo]{ foo.FooFun();} 
        , [&bar]{ bar.BarFun();}
        };

    for( auto& cb : callbacks ) {
        cb();
    }

    return 0;
}
```